# SVM training to infer point position with respect to two other points in a video

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, svm, training-data

I would like to train a SVM with opencv c++ so as to infer the position of a point in the image with respect to two other points to which the wanted point is related.

Basically I have the trajectories of the three points during a whole video and I would like to use these trajectories as training data of the SVM.

I'm new to machine learning techniques and after some readings I think I've understood that SVM will return a boolean result( true if some conditions are satisfied at the same time, false if not). In my case I need a position in the image as result.

I'm not sure how I should organize the training set, I was thinking to do something like that:

T1 T2 T3 label=1

where T1 T2 and T3 contain all the points belonging to the three trajectories that I know as correct;

T1 T2 T4 label=-1

where T1 and T2 are the same as before while T4 contains random points that don't lie on the trajectory T3.

Once I have trained the SVM with different trajectories from different videos I would like to pass three points: P1(x,y) and P2(x,y) corresponding to T1 and T2 at time t and a random point P(x,y), and the SVM should predict if the random point is in the wanted position or not.

anybody could explain me if this approach is wrong and why?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand why to use machine learning to infer the position of a point in the image with respect to two other points to which the wanted point is related. Can you please explain?

Comment: The wanted point follows a trajectory that is similar from video to video, so i would like to use machine learning to infer the position in this trajectory based on the position of the two related points that i know

Answer (score 0):

This approach is wrong mostly because yout problem **is not** a binary classification problem. It is rather a **regression** problem. Your desired output is a **value**, not a binary number, so training SVM, or any other binary classifier is a bad idea. Classification problem is a search for a mapping from your input data into some finite (and small) set of possible labels (like "true" and "false", or "cat", "dog" or "face"). Regression on the other hand is a seek for the mapping from your input data into (possibly multi dimensional) real-valued space, so instead of labels - your are looking for actual **values**. In your case - you seek for **coordinates**, which are (as I suppose) two real numbers. If you model your problem as a binary classification then:

- There is no sensible way of creating a training set (you have only "positive" examples, you can generate "negative" ones by taking points which are not correct, but **most** of them are, it would be better to train a one-class SVM, but as mentioned before - it is **not a classification** problem at all)
- Actual testing would be of horrible complexity, as you have to ask for each point "is it a correct answer?"

Instead, you should train any **regression** model with data of form

```
(point_1, point_2) -> point_3
```

so model can find a function which maps your two input points onto one output point. There are many possible models for this task:

- linear regression
- neural network
- SVR (support vector reggresion)

In short:

- your output is a label, discrete value from the finite set -> classifier
- your output is a continuous value -> reggresion model

If it is still not clear for you, I suggest a good video from the Stanford University:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5RLRKkzYWuQ

Comment: Very good explanation. I had a doubt about training, is there any way of training a neural network to define the occurrence of point???